# How to test an update method in jdbc

Tags: java, database, testing, sql-update

So I have an update method to update the customers and it looks like :

```
public static Customer UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){
    System.out.println("Updating customer ");


    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE customer " + "SET id = " + customer.getCustomerId() + "SET name = " + customer.getName() + "SET tagNo = " + customer.getTagNo() + 
                "SET telephoneNo = " + customer.getTelephoneNo() + "SET email = " + customer.getEmail() + "SET noOfTimesRecycles = " + 
                customer.getNoOfTimesRecycled());


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in updating customer");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return customer;
}
```

Am not sure how to test it though. All I've got upto now for the testing bit is this :

```
public static Customer UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){

    return UpdateCustomer(customer); 
}

public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    connectTest();

    UpdateCustomer(105,"John", 4179, "+4475855216");

            closeTest();
}
```

Well it gives me error at UpdateCustpmer since it's expecting something of Type customer.

Can anyonw help me with this? Thank you

Comment: do you have a stack trace?

Comment: yes I do in that update method

Comment: just a remark: your update statement should not update the customerId, but instead use it as a where criterion for finding the customer to update

Comment: That's what it says:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method UpdateCustomer(Customer) in the type DatabaseInterfaceTest is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, int, String)

 at com.qmul.rfid.dataaccess.DatabaseInterfaceTest.main(DatabaseInterfaceTest.java:97)

Comment: @wxyz I guess what you are saying is really what I want to do but I'm not sure how to test if the method works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way to test is as below.

public static Customer UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){
    System.out.println("Updating customer ");

```
try {
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    String query = "UPDATE customer " + "SET id = " + customer.getCustomerId() + "SET name = " + customer.getName() + "SET tagNo = " + customer.getTagNo() + 
            "SET telephoneNo = " + customer.getTelephoneNo() + "SET email = " + customer.getEmail() + "SET noOfTimesRecycles = " + 
            customer.getNoOfTimesRecycled();

    System.out.println("Update query is:::"+query);
    statement.executeUpdate(query);


} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in updating customer");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

return customer;
```

}

Now, copy the log of "update query is" and paste in database console(mysql or anyother database you'r using). and checks error message in that.

Comment: If you found it as per your expectation then you can up vote it as per stackoverflow standard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `Customer` object to the `UpdateCustomer` method, create an `Customer` object and fill it with your value , then pass it to the `UpdateCustomer` method, like:

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    connectTest();
    Customer customer = new Customer(105,"John", 4179, "+4475855216");// note you should have a constructor takes the passed arguments. or you could use setter methods
    UpdateCustomer(customer);

    closeTest();
}
```

You need to Read about [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) in java

Edit:

You don't need to use `SET` keyword each time, just separate the columns you want to update by a coma, like:

```
public static Customer UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){
    System.out.println("Updating customer ");


    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE customer " + "SET id = " + customer.getCustomerId() + ",name = " + customer.getName() + ",tagNo = " + customer.getTagNo() + 
            ",telephoneNo = " + customer.getTelephoneNo() + ",email = " + customer.getEmail() + "SET noOfTimesRecycles = " + 
            customer.getNoOfTimesRecycled());


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in updating customer");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return customer;
}
```

Comment: I have the constructor in the customer class. This main method is in my test class. Is it fine to create a customer object in that class?

Comment: Yea you should, how you gonna test `Customer` class without creating an object from it.

Comment: Still getting errors with it. 
my code: 
>Customer customer = new Customer(106, "Payton Ley", 4517, "+44745271478", "p.ley@gmail.com", 1);
  UpdateCustomer(customer);
  
it says: errors at com.qmul.rfid.dataaccess.DatabaseInterfaceTest.UpdateCustomer(DatabaseInterfaceTest.java:46)

Comment: This is another error than the one you mentioned above, this error caused by the `updateCustomer` method. see my updated answer.

Comment: tried that but still getting the same error! Thanks anyway!